# Count connected pixels (GEE)

Tags: google-earth-engine, modis, pixel, composite

I am working on a code to detect/count the patches of burned areas in an image. I thought using the function `connectedPixelCount()` in GEE would help me in doing so. However, the latter seems to not work with composite images. Is there a way to make it perceive the composite image as a typical one layer image? (If there is an alternative function for composites, that would solve my issue too)

[Code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Ffarhatlokmen%2Ftests%3Atest)

```
var country = ['ZA'];
var geometry = ee.FeatureCollection('USDOS/LSIB/2013')
                      .filter(ee.Filter.inList('cc', country));
Map.centerObject(geometry, 5);

var modisFire = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MCD64A1')
                  .map(function(image) { return image.clip(geometry);})
                  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2017-06-01', '2017-08-31'))
                  .select('BurnDate');

var date = ee.Date('2017-06-01');
var composite = modisFire.mean().set('system:time_start', date.millis(), 
                                     'dateYMD', date.format('YYYY-MM-dd'), 
                                      'numbImages', modisFire.size());


var img = ee.Image(modisFire.toList(3).get(0));
var img1 = ee.Image(composite);

Map.addLayer(img, {palette: 'red'}, 'June Fire');
Map.addLayer(img, {palette: 'orange'}, 'Summer Fire');

var patches = img1.connectedPixelCount(5, false);
patches = patches.updateMask(patches.gte(5));
Map.addLayer(patches, {palette: 'blue'}, 'Burned Area');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error message give you a hint of what's wrong:

> Burned Area: Layer error: Image.connectedPixelCount: Segment size
>   calculation on floating point bands is not supported. Unsupported
>   type: Type>.

Your `img` is `int16`, while `img1` is `double`. If you cast `img1` to `int16`, you should be good:

```
var patches = img1.int16().connectedPixelCount(5, false);
```

Comment: thanks for the help!